# Check GNU Octave compile flag

Tags: linux, octave

I have GNU Octave installed across different operating systems, and would like to check the compile flag for them. Specifically on RPM-based systems, the Octave package is compiled with `enable64=no`, from https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/g/scitech/octave5.1/

Is there a way to check what are the command line options for octave?

As a workaround, I can declare a large array, for example

```
octave:1> a = zeros (1024*1024*1024*3, 1, 'int8');
error: out of memory or dimension too large for Octave's index type
```

But I would prefer a more definitive way to check Octave's compile flags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See

```
__octave_config_info__.ENABLE_64
```

and

```
__octave_config_info__.build_environment
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be checking for compilation flags because you never know when they will change or what other flags may affect what you really care about.  That is why `__octave_config_info__` is a private function, meant for internal use only.

In your case, it seems that what you really care about is the max number of elements you can have in an array. In that case, you should use `sizemax` (largest value allowed for the size of an array):

```
octave> sizemax 
ans = 9223372036854775806
```

Comment: of course you are right, I'm just tired of these xy-problem questions